# Prevent Esc Key from Exiting FullScreen App Mode on Website

Tags: javascript, html, macos, safari, fullscreen

I'm developing a custom "lightbox" photo gallery. I'm adding key event "listeners" (left>prev, right>next, esc>close), and I'm having the issue of Safari (or any fullscreen mode browser) exiting fullscreen mode on escape. My site works fine, just the viewer then has to resume fullscreen mode for Safari (and others).

Now, I know there's a way to bypass this. Facebook for instance, while looking at a photo in the "theatre" mode, can be closed with the esc key without causing my browser to exit fullscreen.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Does event.preventDefault() not work?

Answer (score 5):

Practically you cannot disable <kbd>ESC</kbd> key for browsers as that is a compromise for user to at least have some control over their browser.
However, you do have a way to bind an eventlistener to your element field (say your lightbox div) to catch the Event when <kbd>Esc</kbd> is pressed and suppress it, like below: (so when people press <kbd>ESC</kbd> over the gallery div it will not exit browser fullscreen)

```
document.querySelector("div.lightbox").addEventListener("keydown",function(e){
    var charCode = e.charCode || e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (charCode == 27){
         alert("Escape is not suppressed for lightbox!");
        return false;
    }
});
```

Also many browsers toggle fullscreen mode with <kbd>F11</kbd> key now.

Comment: Note to the wise: I bashed my head on this for ages before realising I was binding to the keyup event. Make sure you bind your default-preventing handler to the *keydown* event!

Comment: Thanks for the help. This put me on the path to solving the same problem in my app; much obliged! I found that returning false has been deprecated. The correct way to stop further propagation of an event now is to call Event.preventDefault(). See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault