# How to Set variable While Capturing the ESC event when exiting full screen mode?

Tags: javascript, angular, video, video-streaming

I need to set variables while exiting the full-screen mode.

```
  myvariable = false
  @HostListener("dblclick", ['$event'])
  fullScreen(event) {
    console.log("fullScreen()",event)
    if(this.video)
    {
      if (this.video.requestFullscreen) {
        this.video.requestFullscreen();
      } else if (this.video.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        this.video.nativeElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
      } else if (this.video.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
        this.video.webkitRequestFullscreen();
      } else if (this.video.msRequestFullscreen) {
        this.video.msRequestFullscreen();
      }
    }
    if (document.addEventListener) {
      document.addEventListener('webkitfullscreenchange', this.exitHandler);
      document.addEventListener('mozfullscreenchange', this.exitHandler);
      document.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', this.exitHandler);
      document.addEventListener('MSFullscreenChange', this.exitHandler);
  }
    if (document.fullscreenElement) {
      this.myvariable = false
      document.exitFullscreen();
    }
  }
  exitHandler() {
    //this function is called whenever fullscreen and exit the fullscreen mode
    console.log("exitHandler : ",document.fullscreenElement,this.myvariable) // Here it's said undefined in this whole DOM found
    if (document.fullscreenElement === null) {
        this.myvariable = true
    }
  }
```

Is there anyone know? how to restrict the ESC key or how to set the variable in exitHandler()
I tried to restrict ESC using keydown, keypress and keydown But did not capture the event while I am in Video FullScreen Mode and press the ESC key.
I tried many ways but had no luck.

Comment: Maybe look at the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20916109/prevent-esc-key-from-exiting-fullscreen-app-mode-on-website

Comment: @ardentia Thank you for your response. I already tried these 3 events(keypress, keydown, keyup). But When I'm in video fullscreenmode and press the ESC it's not captured. I tried all the other keys. all are captured. but only ESC was not captured.